# How can I know which value raise the error `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.`

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing an ETL processes with some SQL Server procedures.

```
WITH CTE (qty_top, qty_lvl) AS 
(
    SELECT
        CONVERT(decimal(20,6), t.unity),
        CONVERT(decimal(20,6), t.unity)
    FROM
        top_tab 
     
    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CONVERT(decimal(20,6), cte.qty * t.unity),
        CONVERT(decimal(20,6), nom.Nomenclature_unite_production)
    FROM
        CTE_NOM cte
    JOIN
        tab t
)
```

This is my SQL Request (very simplified). When I do this, this raise me an `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.`

I tried to change my `decimal(20,6)` into a bigger number `(30,6)` but it still doesn't work.

How can I know which values raise me this error ? So It can help me to resolve this error.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(20, 6), <expr>) IS NULL`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Should I add `try_convert` to my `convert` too ?